# Awk add Quotes around files column

Tags: awk

I'm working with a tab delimited file and am looking to add quotes around a column #1 and also add an additional quotes (as an escape) if there is a quotes in the string.

Here is the head of the file:

```
auto_type  compact   323
auto_type  truck   219
auto_type  truck 5"  25
```

Desired results:

```
auto_type  "compact"   323
auto_type  "truck"   219
auto_type  "truck 5""  25
```

Here is my initial attempt at at least adding quotes around the column:

```
awk -F, '{print gsub("\"","\"\"",$2)}' OFS=, vehicle_file.txt
```

Comment: Why do you want this? Your desired output doesn't look like an improvement to me, and in fact seems ambiguous. There is a CSV dialect which allows a literal double quote to be embedded in a double-quoted field by doubling it, but here, you aren't doing that, either (and if you don't have tabs in your values, why would you even need this in the first place?)

Comment: Is the desired result really what you want?  Normally, you'd need `"truck 5"""` (three consecutive double quotes) to indicate that the double quote is part of the data.  What you say you want is the same as what you'd get if you ignore the fact that there's a double quote in the data.

Comment: I realize consecutive quotes is strange, but it's required per the requirements of the data load

Answer (score 2):

Your desired output is wrong as it leaves your 2nd field with unmatched double quotes, it should be:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {gsub(/"/,"\"\"",$2); $2="\"" $2 "\""} 1' file
auto_type       "compact"       323
auto_type       "truck" 219
auto_type       "truck 5"""     25
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {gsub(FS,"\""FS); sub(/\"\t/,FS"\"",$0); print $0}' foo
auto_type       "compact"       323
auto_type       "truck" 219
auto_type       "truck 5""      25
```

- first replace all `FS` with `"FS`
- then replace the first `"FS` with `FS"`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to double up the quotes already in the data, you do that before you add quotes around the field.  Hence:

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { gsub(/"/, "\"\"", $2); $2 = "\"" $2 "\""; print }' data |
> pr -e16 -l1 -t
auto_type       "compact"       323
auto_type       "truck"         219
auto_type       "truck 5"""     25
$
```

(The `pr` command expands tabs to 16 spaces because of the `-e16`; it makes them easy to see, and aligns the data.)

If you want the output shown in the question, omit the `gsub`:

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { $2 = "\"" $2 "\""; print }' data | pr -l1 -t -e16
auto_type       "compact"       323
auto_type       "truck"         219
auto_type       "truck 5""      25
$
```

However, this output is not a usable data file for any CSV reader I know of.

Comment: awk interprets `'\t'` when assigned to a variable on the command line (including when setting `FS` with `-F`) as a tab character, no need for the bashism `-F$'\t'` or literal `-F'•'`, just `-F'\t'` will do.

Comment: @EdMorton: That does seem to work with both the BSD (Mac OS X) and GNU versions of `sed`, so I've updated my answer — thanks.  I think the POSIX [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) specification is mildly ambiguous on the point; it certainly discusses `\t` representing tabs in some contexts, so it is consistent to apply it here too (and it simplifies scripting), but I didn't spot the text said it applied to the evaluation of FS.

Comment: Yeah you actually have to jump through some hoops if you DON'T want it interpreted as a tab (and assuming you can't just add an extra escape), i.e. `fs='\t' awk 'BEGIN{FS=ENVIRON["fs"]; printf "<%s>\n", FS}'` or `awk 'BEGIN{FS=ARGV[1]; ARGV[1]=""; printf "<%s>\n", FS}' '\t'`. Basically awk interprets backslashes in command-line variable settings just like shell's `read` does by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{sub($2, "\"&\"")sub(/truck\42 5/,"truck 5\42")}1' file

auto_type  "compact"   323
auto_type  "truck"   219
auto_type  "truck 5""  25
```